# Calculate vector flux throught surface defined by paraboloid and plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am looking for the solution of an exercise that requires calculating the flux of the vector field $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{F}}$ through the surface defined by the plane $z=4$ and the paraboloid $z = x² + y²$.

The calculation must me done using the divergence theorem.

$$\iint_{\partial\Omega} \boldsymbol{\mathrm{F}}\cdot\mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{\mathrm{S}} = \iiint_\Omega \mathrm{div} \, \boldsymbol{\mathrm{F}} \, \mathrm{d}V  $$

where,

$$ \boldsymbol{\mathrm{F}} = \left[\cos{z}+xy², x\exp{(-z)}, \sin y+x²z\right]^T $$

then,

$$\mathrm{div} \, \boldsymbol{\mathrm{F}} = x²+y² = z $$

I really don't know how to find the limits of the triple volume integral.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Before discussing the integration, I have a question: when you compute your divergence, why do you state that $x^2+y^2=z$?

Comment: Because this is the equation of the plane, so I though this would be true on the plane.

Comment: It is the equation of the paraboloid, but I knew what you meant.  When integrating the divergence over $\Omega$, you must understand that $\Omega$ is a solid region, not a surface, so $z$ will be constrained by inequalities rather than a specific equation.

Comment: Yes of course it's the equation of the paraboloid, not of the plane, sorry.
I understand what you meant about the inequalities, thank you. But I really don't know how to find them.

Comment: I would recommend sketching a picture of the paraboloid and the plane to visualize the region $\Omega$ which is contained by these two surfaces.

Comment: The paraboloid has four "branches" going to infinity in the $z$ direction right? [Like that](https://i.postimg.cc/XvPDXM8M/MSP5771each2ce0d6h0h6600003716gb07c2ba5fg5.gif).

Comment: If you were to take horizontal cross-sections of the paraboloid, you would always get circles, so thinking of branches isn't exactly right.  If you sketch both the paraboloid and plane $z=4$ together, you should begin to see the region $\Omega$ and what bounds for $z$ would be appropriate (these bounds are, of course, given in the answer shown below as well).

Comment: I can see the circle and that the upper bound for $z$ is 4. Since we don't have any condition for the lower bound, I guess we can write $x²+y² \leq z \leq 4$.

Comment: $\Omega$ is supposed to be the region bounded by $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=4$, so the is bounded below by the paraboloid and above by the plane.  This is why your $z$ inequality is correct.

Comment: I don't understand how I can write that $\Omega$ is bounded below by the paraboloid in another way since the only information that I have is the paraboloid's equation.

Comment: I said your inequality is *correct*, I just wanted you to understand why.

Comment: Oh yes sorry I misread you, I am not used to be correct... Thank you for your help, I think next I'll be able to find the inequality. I still don't understand the calculus' steps of the answer shown below.

Answer (score 0):

$\iint_{D}\int^{4}_{x^{2}+y^{2}}z dzdxdy$ where $D$ is the intersection of ${x^{2}+y^{2}}=4$

Let $x=r \cos(\theta)$ and  $y=r \sin(\theta)$ then $0\le r\le 2$ and $0\le \theta\le 2\pi$

Therefore
$\iint_{D}\int^{4}_{x^{2}+y^{2}}z dzdxdy$=$\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int^{2}_{0} \frac{r^{4}}{2}r drd\theta$

Comment: I don't understand how you have $r⁴$ only as integrand since for me $\iint_D\int_{x²+y²}^4 z \, \mathrm{d} z \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d} y = \iint_D \left[ \frac{z^2}{2} \right]_{r²}^4 \mathrm{d} S = \iint_D \left(8 - \frac{r^4}{2} \right) \mathrm{d} S$